# Is it possible to call a Method inside another Meteor.call?

Tags: meteor

I've got two methods on a same event `click .open-message` :

- `sendEmailContact` : this method send a mail
- `openMessage` : this method update the message (from `new state` to `responded state`)

The two methods are working fine, but separately.

My idea is to pass `Meteor.call('sendEmailContact'` and on success only, to pass `Meteor.call('openMessage'`

Below my current event & my unsuccess try

**current event**

```
Template.Users.events({
    'click .open-message':function() {
        Meteor.call('openMessage', this._id, function(error) {
            if(error) {
                Bert.alert({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: error.reason,
                    type: 'danger'
                });
            } else {console.log ("ok");}
        });
        var to = this.email; // catch the to value
        var contactmessage = this.message; // catch the original message
        swal({
          input: 'textarea',
          title: "Response to " + to,
          text: "H " + contactmessage,
          type: "",
          showCloseButton: true,
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#272b35",
          confirmButtonText: "Send"
        }).then(function (text){
            if(message != '') {
            var from = "my@mail.com"
            var subject = "Response to your message";
            var message = text; //catch the value of the textarea
            Meteor.call('sendEmailContact', to, from, subject, message, contactmessage, (error) => {
                if(error) {
                    Bert.alert({
                        title: 'Error',
                        message: error.reason,
                        type: 'danger'
                    });
                    console.log (to);
                    console.log (from);
                    console.log (subject);
                    console.log (message);
                } else {
                    console.log (to);
                    console.log (from);
                    console.log (subject);
                    console.log (message);
                    //target.text.value = ''; // Clear form
                    Bert.alert({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Message sended.',
                        type: 'success'
                    });
                }
            });
            } else {
                Bert.alert({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'Message error.',
                    type: 'danger'
                });
                console.log (to);
                console.log (from);
                console.log (subject);
                console.log (message);
            }
        }, function (dismiss) {
            if (dismiss === 'cancel') {
                null
                //handle dismiss events like 'cancel', 'overlay', 'close', and 'timer'
            }
        })
    }
});
```

**unsuccess try (no error, the first method ok, but nothing on the second (`console.log ("ok");` works))**

```
Template.Users.events({
    'click .open-message':function() {
        var to = this.email; // catch the to value
        var contactmessage = this.message; // catch the original message
        swal({
          input: 'textarea',
          title: "Response to " + to,
          text: "H " + contactmessage,
          type: "",
          showCloseButton: true,
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#272b35",
          confirmButtonText: "Send"
        }).then(function (text){
            if(message != '') {
            var from = "my@mail.com"
            var subject = "Response to your message";
            var message = text; //catch the value of the textarea
            Meteor.call('sendEmailContact', to, from, subject, message, contactmessage, (error) => {
                if(error) {
                    Bert.alert({
                        title: 'Error',
                        message: error.reason,
                        type: 'danger'
                    });
                    console.log (to);
                    console.log (from);
                    console.log (subject);
                    console.log (message);
                } else {
                    Meteor.call('openMessage', this._id, function(error) {
                        if(error) {
                            Bert.alert({
                                title: 'Error',
                                message: error.reason,
                                type: 'danger'
                            });
                        } else {console.log ("ok");}
                    });
                    console.log (to);
                    console.log (from);
                    console.log (subject);
                    console.log (message);
                    //target.text.value = ''; // Clear form
                    Bert.alert({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Message sended.',
                        type: 'success'
                    });
                }
            });
            } else {
                Bert.alert({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'Message error.',
                    type: 'danger'
                });
                console.log (to);
                console.log (from);
                console.log (subject);
                console.log (message);
            }
        }, function (dismiss) {
            if (dismiss === 'cancel') {
                null
                //handle dismiss events like 'cancel', 'overlay', 'close', and 'timer'
            }
        })
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Below the two methods :

```
//Contact Method
Meteor.methods({
    insertMessage: function(message) {
        ContactMessages.insert(message);
    },
    openMessage: function(messageId) {
        ContactMessages.update({_id: messageId}, {$set: {new: false, responded: true}});
    },
    deleteMessage: function(messageId) {
        ContactMessages.remove({_id: messageId});
    }
});

//Send ContactReply Method
Meteor.methods({
    sendEmailContact: function(to, from, subject, message, contactmessage) {
        check([to, from, subject, message, contactmessage], [String]);

        // Let other method calls from the same client start running,
        // without waiting for the email sending to complete.
        this.unblock();

        Email.send({
          to: to,
          from: from,
          subject: subject,
          text: message + contactmessage
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You should make a single server call from the client `Meteor.call()` and have the first method invoke the second just on the server side. Save the roundtrip.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Could you help me to do so (`openMessage` invoked in the `sendEmailContact` method) : tried with no success.. The two methods are at the bottom of my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass the `messageId` as an extra parameter to `sendEmailContact` from the client but then it should be pretty simple:

```
Meteor.methods({
    insertMessage(message) {
        ContactMessages.insert(message);
    },
    openMessage(messageId) {
        ContactMessages.update(messageId, {$set: {new: false, responded: true}});
    },
    deleteMessage(messageId) {
        ContactMessages.remove(messageId);
    }
});

//Send ContactReply Method
Meteor.methods({
    sendEmailContact(messageId,to, from, subject, message, contactmessage) {
        check([messageId, to, from, subject, message, contactmessage], [String]);
        this.unblock();
        Email.send({
          to: to,
          from: from,
          subject: subject,
          text: message + contactmessage
        });
        Meteor.call('openMessage',messageId);
    }
});
```

You don't even need a callback from the embedded `Meteor.call()` unless you want to log a potential error there.

Comment: There's still an error on the client call (all var are defined) `Meteor.call('sendEmailContact', to, from, subject, message, contactmessage, (error) => {` Do I need to do some modifications here too?

Comment: I manage it myself, was quite obvious sorry. `var messageId = this._id;` and then `Meteor.call('sendEmailContact', messageId, to, from, subject, message, contactmessage, (error) => {` Thanks Michel

Answer (score 0):

in your 2nd example:

```
Meteor.call('openMessage', this._id, function(error) {
```

i think it doesn't know what "this" is.

so save it off at the top of the function and use the saved value through closure.

i'm also wondering why it's important that the client be the one to invoke both methods. it's technically possible to handle all that on the server; is that something that makes sense in your app?

Comment: It makes a lot of sense to handle the `openMessage` in the `sendEmailContact` method. I've edited my question : can you help to proceed it?

Comment: look at my answer again: "this._id" isn't working because "this" is no longer valid in that context. i bet if you tried to console.log(this._id) it will be undefined, or not what you expect.

Comment: You're right, but I think, like you, that calling a method inside a call is not the best.. Is it possible to merge the two methods ? Would be better, no? Just one call.